# Creative Gigaworks T3 sub with different speakers

Tags: audio, compatibility, audio-conversion

I was hoping someone might know something more about how audio works and let me know whether this is compatible or not.

I would like to use my Gigaworks T3 sub with my Gigaworks T40 speakers. The speakers that had come with the sub have died and now I feel like I'm wasting a perfectly good sub. I just bought the T40's and they have their own power supply unlike the old speakers. The sub outs 4ohms, I'm guessing this would harm the T40's if I plugged them in.

However, that is all assumption and I would like to hear what I might be able to do from someone who knows a bit more about audio connections and things of that sort.

Below are the links to the actual products themselves so that you can easily look at their specs.

[Gigaworks T3](http://us.creative.com/p/speakers/gigaworks-t3)
[Gigaworks T40 Series II](http://us.creative.com/p/speakers/gigaworks-t40-series-ii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The T40s are full range speakers - they don't need an amplifier to get the full range out of them, and have their own power supply. The subwoofer on the other hand has a [crossover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_crossover) and will only send higher frequency signals to their satellite speakers, so you're losing out on full range of the T40s. You're also sending an amplified signal to a pair of amplified speakers so, you may end up driving them harder than they need to be. In short, not the greatest idea.

On the *other* hand, there's a smarter way to do this - if you have a 5.1 capable sound card, why not set up the T3's sub as a center/subwoofer, and the T40s as your front speakers. You have the same effect (MOAR BASS), without risking blowing anything up.

[image]

Comment: Ah someone does know the answer.  Thank you for explaining this to me.

Comment: As someone who has a set of T3s, this is good to know and will give me something to consider if I ever feel the need to upgrade. @KirsKringle - Please update this with how well it works, I'd be genuinely interested in finding out.

Comment: I currently do not have a 5.1 capable sound card. I use a laptop and I have the xi-fi go.  So I cannot try this @MichaelFrank  However, I might just split the main output connection and have it go to both.  I feel though that this will cause timing issues.

Comment: Only one way to find out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is damaging, but plugged them into the 4ohms out and it just amps them up louder.  So I guess it is fine.  I'm sure it damages something somewhere though.